# .Net - Problemas a la hora de usar AutoMapper en WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, automapper

Estoy intentando montar AutoMapper en mi WebApi pero me da un error. He cargado las librerias con nuget y he puesto las siguientes lineas.

En el archivo WebApiConfig.cs incluyo lo siguiente:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile<App_Start.AutoMapperConfig>();
    cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = false;
});
```

y la clase AutoMapperConfig contiene el siguiente codigo:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig : Profile
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize((config) =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<Model.Client, DTO.ClientBasic>();
        });
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase de dominio:

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Secret { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Index("Client_ClientCode", IsUnique = true)]
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    public ApplicationTypes ApplicationType { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int RefreshTokenLifeTime { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string AllowedOrigin { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatorId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RefreshToken> RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> Role { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
    public User Creator { get; set; }
}
```

Y este mi DTO:

```
public class ClientBasic
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Secret { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationType { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int RefreshTokenLifeTime { get; set; }
    public string AllowedOrigin { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatorId { get; set; }
}
```

Hago la llamada al Mapper desde mi metodo en WebApi para transformar el objeto Client de base de datos en el objeto que voy a devolver:

```
List<Model.Client> clients = _ClientService.SelectAll().ToList();
return this.Ok(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<DTO.ClientController.ClientBasic>>(clients));
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
{Message: "Error.",…}
ExceptionMessage
:
"Error mapping types.
↵
↵Mapping types:
↵List`1 -> List`1
↵System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MGA.Model.Client, MGA.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MGA.WebApi.DTO.ClientController.ClientBasic, MGA.WebApi.DTO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"
ExceptionType
:
"AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException"
InnerException
:
{Message: "Error.",…}
ExceptionMessage
:
"↵Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.↵Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type↵For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters↵================================================================
↵AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
↵Client -> ClientBasic (Destination member list)
↵MGA.Model.Client -> MGA.WebApi.DTO.ClientController.ClientBasic (Destination member list)
↵
↵Unmapped properties:
↵SecretText
↵"
ExceptionType
:
"AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException"
Message
:
"Error."
StackTrace
:
"   en AutoMapper.ConfigurationValidator.AssertConfigurationIsValid(IEnumerable`1 typeMaps)
↵   en AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid(TypeMap typeMap)
↵   en lambda_method(Closure , List`1 , List`1 , ResolutionContext )"
Message
:
"Error."
StackTrace
:
"   en lambda_method(Closure , List`1 , List`1 , ResolutionContext )
↵   en lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object , ResolutionContext )
↵   en AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TDestination](Object source)
↵   en AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TDestination](Object source)
↵   en MGA.WebApi.Controllers.ClientController.Get() en C:\Proyectos\MGA\MGA.WebApi\Controllers\ClientController.cs:línea 45
↵   en lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
↵   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__3(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
↵   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
↵   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
↵--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
↵   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
↵--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
↵   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
↵--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
↵   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   en System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
↵--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
↵   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"
```

Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando ???

Comment: Yo no uso automapper, pero por la excepción que te da entiendo que el problema es que `Client` tiene más propiedades que `ClientBasic`, con lo que debes generar una conversión personalizada.

Comment: Yo suelo usar esa librería en mas proyectos y hago cosas similares sin problemas... funciona bien y mapea las propiedades que se encuentran en ambas clases, omitiendo el resto... es mas, tengo DTOs con campos calculados (se calculan cuando mapeo el dominio en el dto) y va sin problemas...

Comment: Aclaro que los otros proyectos ya lo tenia montado, este es el primero que monto de cero y las versiones del AutoMapper son distintas en los proyectos...